# How Python code know a remote bluetooth classic device is really connected?

Tags: python, bluetooth, pyserial

I am working with Python 3.10 on a Linux Mint 21 machine.

Several HC-06 and HC-05 modules are bound to serial devices with lines like:

`sudo rfcomm bind 7 98:DA:50:01:46:77`

to give me devices like

`/dev/rfcomm7`

These, of course, exist on the PC regardless of whether the actual BT module is even powered on let alone has a functioning radio link. Similarly, Windows pairing would create permanently available COM ports.

I want to connect to these devices in Python using pyserial. A simple declaration that 'just works' for directly connected serial devices would be something like:

`serial_port = serial.Serial(port='/dev/rfcomm7')`

That will always succeed if the device exists but I want to know when/if the radio link is established. The BT module may not be sending any data at the time of connections and is not necessarity replying to bytes sent to it. I just want to know when the radio link is up. At the moment, the best I seem to be able to do is write a single character to the device and wait to see if it gets sent within some timeout period. I have a test function for this (clearly I would trim out the debugging output):

```
def connect_port(serial_port):
    '''
    Given an open port, test for the presence of an actual device.
    BT devices take time to establish the radio link so we
    need to wait for that and see if the device at the other
    end of the link is really there 
    '''
    # try to send a single byte to the device
    # If there is not actual connection, the byte will
    # get stuck in the outbound queue and eventually cause
    # an error. On Linux Mint 21 that seems to take about 
    # 5-6 seconds
    serial_port.write(b' ')
    wait_period = 10.0  # seconds
    sys.stdout.write('Waiting for data ')
    start_time = time.time()
    i = -1
    while time.time() - start_time < wait_period:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        try:
            i = serial_port.out_waiting
        except OSError as e:
            print(f'{e.strerror}, Port not available')
            i = -1
            break
        else:
            if i == 0:
                break
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    if i == 0:
        print(f'\nReady after {elapsed_time:.3f} seconds')
        return True
    else:
        print(f'\nNot ready after {elapsed_time:.3f} seconds')
        return False
```

Is this an adequate method of detecting the link? Is there some simpler or more robust method available?

All the searches I have done so far just assume that the module is powered on and will connect, then you are good to go. Anyone who has played with these things knows that life is seldom so accommodating.